# HTML save text in textarea

Tags: html, save, textarea

I have this text box

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="100"> </textarea>
```

When someones enters text into it and refreshes the page how do I make the text inputted stay there

I would attempt something myself but I do not know where to start...

Comment: You will need to use either ajax or a server side language.

Comment: You are now moving out of the markup language, into what is called programming/scripting this can be done in either JavaScript or PHP depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Jquery and local storage like this. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/13/

This will work with multiple `<textarea>`'s

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     $('textarea').each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, value);
    }); 
}
window.onload = function() {        
    $('textarea').each(function(){    
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var text2 = localStorage.getItem(id);
       if (text2 !== null) $('#'+id).val(text2);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I know it works on the jsfiddle but for some reason in dreamweaver it doesn't work when I preview in browser

Comment: @Ofcdan you need to link jquery in the `<head>` section, use this `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`